# create a view for all history for a record from Audit History in CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using CRM 2016 and I enabled Audit History for All customized entity.
Now I need to show up all changes made for a chosen record only, from audit History.

I know that I can see the changes in "Audit summery view" but the problem is that, Audit View summery lists all changes for all entities and records.

Anyone can help me in this?
regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the record itself, use the dropdown in the nav bar to see the associated views and select Audit History:

[image: Access Audit History]

Then you will see the changes for that record:

[image: A Contact's Audit History]

Comment: Also, the Contact Audit History has its own filter that can be applied to view only audited changes for a **particular field**